# Crashed when deleting a row from UItableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

When deleting a row from **Uitableview** using commitEditingStyle, my app crashes with this error.

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046 .Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The
>   number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2)
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
>   from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
      order *OrderObj= [appDelegate.orderArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
       [appDelegate removeitem:OrderObj];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change these lines:

```
order *OrderObj= [appDelegate.orderArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[appDelegate removeitem:OrderObj];
```

to:

```
[appDelegate.orderArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; // assuming orderArray is NSMutableArray
```

Comment: Thanks for replying..Your answer will remove the item from tableview,but I need to delete the item database too..

Comment: @nithin. then just add my line to your lines without removing  :). I guess you lines remove object from db, but crash appear because you have incorrect count of objects in orderArray

Answer (score 6):

Your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning bad value after the update. Check the value returned before delete and after delete. It must be decreased by 1.